# PriviledgedActionException while running mapreduce using kerberos authentication

Tags: java, mapreduce, kerberos

> Getting PriviledgedActionException                                         as:user(auth:KERBEROS)cause:java.io.IOException:                                 java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

While login 1st time with **UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab**
and running job everything works fine.
After ticket expiry and relogin i get

> "Login successful for user "

but job fails with

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.addDelegationTokens(KMSClientProvider.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyProviderDelegationTokenExtension.addDelegationTokens(KeyProviderDelegationTokenExtension.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.addDelegationTokens(DistributedFileSystem.java:2056)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1303)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1303)
    ....
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1684)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.addDelegationTokens(KMSClientProvider.java:869)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
```

on debugging i found exception is coming at `Subject.doAs(subject, action)` in *addDelegationTokens* inside the job .

How can I solve this issue?

> I am using cdh5.4.3 and java8

Comment: Not sure you can *solve* the issue, but you can *debug* it > https://www.gitbook.com/book/steveloughran/kerberos_and_hadoop/details sections 14-15-16

Comment: Also, what are the **exact** versions of Hadoop and of the JDK? There are known regressions about **TGT renewal** with early Hadoop 2.6.x versions vs. late JDK 1.7.x / 1.8.x (plus Kerberos bugs in some specific JDK versions). Make sure that your JDK matches Cloudera supported version.

Comment: Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.3 and jdk1.8.0_71

Comment: Might be related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10786 >> any chance you can switch to **1.8.0_40** that is the **latest certified version** for CDH 5.4.3 cf. http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/cdh/5-4-3.html

Comment: Changed jdk version still getting the same error.
When running code like
Filesystem fs =filesystem.get(conf)  outside job debug goes at
Subject.doAs(subject, action) 
But no exception is thrown .
Only after submitting the job for run priviledgeActionException is thrown and job fails.

Comment: I found ticket(hex) to be missing in  subject once and then the exception occurred.

Comment: Debugging further into KMSClientProvider.addDelegationTokens()..found that actual exception is thrown at authenticator.authenticate(URL,token); 
Its strange that even URL remain same it run successfully first time but fails after relogin